# raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word) for gensim model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, similarity

I loaded a gensim continuous skipgram model from `http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/#` built on Google News 2013 with a vocabulary size of 2883863. However, I am getting an error message for any two random words I'm trying to get a similarity on.

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'C:\Users\Projects\NLPL\model.txt', binary=False)
model.similarity('president','minister')
```

While loading the model I also tried the binary file instead of `txt`file but that didn't work either.

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'C:\Users\Projects\NLPL\model.bin', binary=True)
```

Also for the similarity score, I tried using unicode characters in the parameters but that didn't work either.

```
model.similarity(u'president',u'minister')
```

I'm pretty sure it is a huge corpus and should have these words and not sure why I'm not getting the results. I also tried some other common words such as `weapon`, military, car, etc. but a same error message.

Comment: If your question could be edited to clearly show the full error stack displayed in response to each bit of code you've tried, it'd be easier to see what might be going wrong. (Generally, if you you get a `KeyError`/`not in voabulary` error, the word is genuinely missing from what you've loaded. Perhaps your files are corrupt/truncated or not what you think they are, if they're missing common English words?)

Comment: @gojomo thanks for your response. I will try the code again and post the full error message. Most likely i am doing something wrong with the way I am looking for the word vectors itself.

Comment: In my experience, the canonical `GoogleNews` vector sets **aren't** provided with filenames like `model.txt` – so you may not be working with the data you think you are. If the `KeyedVectors.load()` succeeded without error, you've got something in `model`. (Enabling logging at the `INFO` level may shed more light.) But also, you can peek at the 1st ten words in the model with something like `model.entity2index[:10]`, which might hint what you've got.

Comment: @gojomo thanks for those useful pointers, will check in that direction and get back with what I find. Appreciate your time and help :)